Support function of a set given by convex constraints
So I have found that for set $\mathcal{Z}=\{\zeta|\,h_k(\zeta)\leq0,\,k=1,\dots,K\}$ for $h_k$ convex the support function of $\mathcal{Z}$ has the form
$$\delta^*(y|\mathcal{Z})=\sup_\zeta\{y^\top\zeta|\,h_k(\zeta)\leq0,\,k=1,\dots,K\}=\inf_{u_k\geq0}(\sum_{k=1}^K u_kh_k)^*(y)$$
where $(\sum_{k=1}^K u_kh_k)^*(y)$ is the convex conjugate of $\sum_{k=1}^K u_kh_k$. Which is given by
$$(\sum_{k=1}^K u_kh_k)^*(y)=\sup_\zeta\{y^\top\zeta-\sum_{k=1}^K u_kh_k(\zeta)\}.$$
But I can't find a way to actually prove it. Does anyone know how to do it?
